# Как убрать лишние слова из строки в python

Tags: python, excel, xlrd

Есть таблица [dump.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fvIYgLVc0Dg3QvYKHS9DUWbrWmGPoRporp0dev-bgyc/edit?usp=sharing)

Мне необходимо на основе данных, которые есть в таблице, записать эти данные в новый файл в формате **.csv**. Файл csv для текуший таблицы [dump.xlsx](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fvIYgLVc0Dg3QvYKHS9DUWbrWmGPoRporp0dev-bgyc/edit?usp=sharing) выглядет следующим образом.

```
directory_preview_v2,directory-service,28.0.0,    <- обязательно запятая в конце
find_cli,find-cli,9.1.0,
```

Необходимо сделать это на питоне.

Comment: если в итоге информация у тебя только в таком виде, то ты можеш взять срезом, сперва няйдя позицию символа "_"

Comment: можете привести пример исходных данных (4-5 строк) в __текстовом__ виде (например в виде CSV) и ожидаемый результат?

Comment: в dump.xlsx A1=AWSPROD4CATALOG-PREVIEW-V2STACK_catalog_preview_v2 B1=registry.dp-dev.jcpcloud2.net/catalog-service:26.0.0. Ожидаемый результат 
 записывает в файл text.csv **catalog_preview_v2,catalog-service,26.0.0,**

Comment: Ссылка на выложенный файл требует подтверждения email'а и как следствие ведет к "засвечиванию" email'а. Лично я не хотел бы показывать вам свой email address для того чтобы помочь вам с вашим вопросом... ;)

Comment: Исправил и теперь доступно без подтверждения

Answer (score 2):

Для обработки данных в CSV, Excel, SQL (и много других форматов) я предпочитаю пользоваться модулем Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = r'D:\download\dump.xlsx'

# parse Excel file into a DataFrame
df = pd.read_excel(filename, usecols="B,E")

# get rid of `prefix_` in the 'NAME' column
df['NAME'] = df['NAME'].str.partition('_', expand=False).str[-1]

# parse a string "address/image:number" into two columns ['IMAGE','NUM']
df[['IMAGE','NUM']] = df['IMAGE'].str.replace(r'.*\/', '').str.split(':', expand=True)

# add an empty column, which is needed for showing a coma
# at the end of each line in the CSV file  
df['EMPTY'] = ""

# save DF as a CSV file
df.to_csv(r'd:/temp/result.csv', header=None, index=False)
```

PS для чтения Excel файлов `Pandas` по умолчанию использует модуль `xlrd`.

Результат:

```
In [28]: from pathlib import Path

In [29]: print(Path(r'd:/temp/result.csv').read_text())
directory_preview_v2,directory-service,28.0.0,
find_cli,find-cli,9.1.0,
```

Comment: Могли бы вы, пожалуйста, привести пример, если например таблица имеет множество столбцов и рядов? При этом все данные почти похожи на те, что были даны выше.

Comment: @IgorSamarskiy, именно поэтому я попросил привести пример входных и выходных данных (это лучше сделать [отредактировав вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/881269/edit)). В ответе я исходил из того что нужные вам данные находяться в первой строке. Остальные строки проигнорируются... Если надо обработать все строки то просто уберите параметр `nrows=1`

Comment: Переделал вопрос, надеюсь теперь более понятная цель.

Comment: @IgorSamarskiy, вы пробовали запускать код из моего ответа?

Comment: Нет, поскольку не совсем понял то как он работает, если я его скопирую в своей.